# MySQL, retrieve field from search

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL with PHP, i have already created a database and a script to populate the database, What i have is a form that inserts an id and an email.

Now what i need to do is create a script that searches for the ID and then once it finds the exact ID i can get the email that was also associated with that ID and do something with it.

What is the correct way to search the database based on one field and then extract the other field?

Comment: Why the downvoting? Just coz he's new? At least send him on his way with a tutorial? http://w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp

Comment: pretty much i'm looking for a good PDO tutorial now since i've learned the original method is deprecated. I've found a minor resource but seems to be a bit confusing. Thanks tho Prof83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Warning:**
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
>
> Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should give some details about deciding which API to use. For PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

This is relatively easy. After your connection has been set up (assuming `$connection` as the pointer), you just need to execute the following query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users_table WHERE user_id = 1", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Your requested e-mail value will be accessible as `$row['email']`.

However, once you have satisfied a level of knowledge in using MySQL with PHP, **heed the warning** and switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @StaticExtasy You're welcome. Please take your time and read the [official manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for the `mysql_query()` function. Also, there are useful comments around on the documentation and you should venture out and look at other methods referenced in the left-side navigation bar. If an answer **is** the one that helped you the most and solved your question, accept it by clicking on the transparent arrow symbol next to it. Other users searching for your problem will see the answer more easily.

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial available or know of where i can search for one to use PDO since the original API has been deprecated, i'll have to convert my original script over so hopefully some good beginner material is around?

Comment: I meant with tutorial with Forms in mind.

Answer (score 2):

SQL enables you to do this very simply:

```sql
SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = 123
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems you look for somesthing like SELECT:

eg.: `SELECT email FROM <table> WHERE ID=<id>`

Comment: how do i put that into a variable for use?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE ID=".$userid;

Answer (score 0):

Look, you're new, here's a tutorial:

http://w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp

But like Whisperity said, learn it, and move over to PDO as soon as you can

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com, not to mention that link answers are discouraged.

Comment: The guy needs a tutorial

Comment: Okay, that doesn't justify using a site that promotes bad practices, though.

Comment: OK ill admit, w3schools was an ancient place to learn when I was starting out... just thought; right at the beginning :)

Comment: The better advice is to forget about `mysql_` and go directly to PDO or mysqli.